# HealthChecker for Java Process

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice

I want to create a health checker, which will check the health of a java process. My process does a lot of things and is multi threaded. Various exceptions could be thrown, like Service / SQL / IO, etc. My plan is to call the `HealthChecker` to check for the process, from the catch block, in the individual threads. This will check for all the different healths, and in the case where there is any issue it will pause the threads, and log appropriately. There will be other processes which will read the logs by the process, and alert support to take appropriate actions.

Below is the general structure of the java process.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Schedular {
    private static int numOfTasks = 10 ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        while(true){
            for(int i=0;i<numOfTasks;i++){
                service.execute(new Workers());
            }
        }
    }
}

class Workers implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /*
         * This can throw different exceptions , eg:    
         */
        try{

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            HealthChecker.checkHealth();
        }
    }
}

class HealthChecker{
    public static void checkHealth() {
        //Check health and then , log and pause all the threads 

    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out a way to pause all the threads. If there is a db exception I want all the threads to pause. I am requesting some suggestions.

Comment: This is not a very good idea. Why do you need to pause all the threads? What's wrong with having the code handle its own logging? It knows a lot better what to log than your `HealthChecker` class.

Comment: As for tracking a process and raising alerts, you may want to read up on JMX.

Comment: This question really needs some cleanup.  You're implying several different questions: 1.  What is the best practice for monitoring the health of threads?  2.  How do I monitor the health of my threads?  3.  How do I stop/pause a running thread?  Cleaning up the question such that you are only asking 1 question will yield better answers.

Comment: Why is there a `while(true)` loop in your main thread?

Comment: @Kayaman - We wanted all the thread to wait till the issue is fixed. @ Jose Martinez in the actual code , I will use a boolean variable instead of true.

Comment: @Anupam You think that you can pause the threads, fix the issue, then continue without problems?

Comment: @Anupam, i provided my answer before I saw your response to my question about the while(true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to block the threads until some event occurs that allows the threads to continue.  I see some major issues with the code:

1)  The `while(true)` in your main thread might lead to a `StackOverflowError`.  With each iteration of the while loop, you will add 10 more threads to the executor, and this will just continue unbounded.

2)  There is no loop in your run() so that even if an exception is caught and we wait for the HealthCheck, the run() method would still exit.  While a loop is not needed in your run() if you can constantly execute new Threads from your main thread to take the place of the terminated one, but that logic is not presently there in the main loop.

But setting those concerns aside here is one way to block worker threads until some event (presumably a HealthCheck all clear) occurs.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Schedular {
    private static int numOfTasks = 10 ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        HealtchChecker hChecker = new HealthChecker();
        for(int i=0;i<numOfTasks;i++){
            service.execute(new Workers(hChecker));
        }
    }
}

class Workers implements Runnable{

    private HealtchChecker hChecker;

    public Workers(HealtchChecker hChecker){
        this.hChecker = hChecker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /*
         * This can throw different exceptions , eg:    
         */
         while(true) {
            try{

            }catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                throw ie;   
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                HealthChecker.checkHealth();
            }
         }
    }
}

class HealthChecker implements Runnable {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

    public void checkHealth() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //code to check for errors that cause threads to pause.
        if (inErrorState) {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } else {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

}
```

A few things worth mentioning.

1)  The main thread only creates 10 threads, versus an unbounded amount.  You can adjust this as needed.

2)  The Worker thread is long lived, meaning it will continue running even if it encounters Exceptions, except for an InterruptException.

3)  HealthCheck is no longer a static object.  it is instead a shared object.

4)  HealthCheck is a runnable that can be executed in its own thread for monitoring for errors.  I did not add the code to execute this thread.

5)  HealCheck uses a Semaphore to cause the threads to block until the error state is cleared.  I looked for other objects that can do this, like CountDownLatch or CyclicBarrier  or Phaser, but this one came closest to giving us what we need to block all the threads from one point (the run() method).

Its not perfect but I think it gets you a little bit closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're venturing pretty far afield from best practices, but you didn't ask about best practices for monitoring the health of threads - so I won't answer that question.  Instead, I'll just answer the question you asked: how can I pause a set of threads managed by an ExecutorService?

Assuming that your `Workers.run()` will eventually end without intervention (in other words, it's not in an infinite loop - intentional or otherwise), the right thing to do is to call `service.shutdown()` (where service is your instance of ExecutorService).  To do this, you can pass service in to `HealthCheck.healthCheck()` as a new parameter.  Calling shutdown() will allow the currently-running threads to complete, then stop the executor.

If `Workers.run()` will not naturally complete, best practice says that you need to change your code such that it will.  There is a `Thread.stop()` method you can call to halt the thread and a `Thread.suspend()` method you can call to suspend the thread.  Both of these are double-bad ideas for you to use for two reasons:

1. They are Deprecated and will leave the Threads in a super-unhealthy state.  You will have very difficult problems in the future if you use them.
2. You are using ExecutorService.  That means you are delegating thread management to that class. If you go messing with the state of the Threads underneath ExecutorService, it can't manage the thread pool for you and, again, you will have very difficult problems in the future.